# call to function inside jQuery-ui plugin has wrong context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, scope, closures

I have a jQuery UI function, inside the _create function I have `var self = this` so I can access the plugin context from other functions in the plugin.

I also have this code inside the _create function:

```
//setup sortable handler
if (self.options.sortable !== false) {

     var soptions = {
         items:'.tagit-choice',
         containment:'parent',
         start:function (event, ui) {
             console.log('sorting started', event, ui);
             self._sortable.tag = $(ui.item);
             self._sortable.origIndex = self._sortable.tag.index();
         },
         update:function (event, ui) {
             console.log('sorting started', event, ui);
             self._sortable.newIndex = self._sortable.tag.index();
             self._moveTag(self._sortable.origIndex, self._sortable.newIndex);
             console.log('moved tag', self._sortable.origIndex, 'to', self._sortable.newIndex);

         }
     };

     if (self.options.sortable == 'handle') {
         $('.tagit-choice', this.element).prepend('<a class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical" style="float:left"></a>');
         soptions.handle = 'a.ui-icon';
         soptions.cursor = 'move';
     }

     self.element.sortable(soptions);
 }
```

To setup sortable inside the plugin.

It has a call to `self._moveTag` where inside I am calling `console.log(self)` which I expect `self` to be the plugin instance, but instead it is the `DOMWindow`. Why is this?

```
_moveTag: function (old_index, new_index) {
    console.log(self);
    self.tagsArray.splice(new_index, 0, self.tagsArray.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
    for (var ind in self.tagsArray)
        self.tagsArray[ind].index = ind;

    if(self.options.select){
        $('option:eq(' + old_index + ')', this.select).insertBefore($('option:eq(' + new_index + ')', this.select));
    }
},
```

---

Hopefully this example is clearer:

```
(function($) {

    $.widget("ui.widgetName", {

        options: {
            sortable: true
        },

        _sortable: {},

        _create: function() {

            var self = this;

            if (self.options.sortable !== false) {
                self.element.sortable({
                    items: '.tagit-choice',
                    containment: 'parent',
                    start: function(event, ui) {
                        self._sortable.tag = $(ui.item);
                        self._sortable.origIndex = self._sortable.tag.index();
                    },
                    update: function(event, ui) {
                        self._sortable.newIndex = self._sortable.tag.index();
                        self._moveTag(self._sortable.origIndex, self._sortable.newIndex);
                    }
                });
            }
        },

        _moveTag: function(old_index, new_index) {
            console.log(self); // <-- this returns DOMWindow?!?!?
        }
    });
})(jQuery);​
```

Comment: Can you narrow this down to a small complete example? It is difficult to tell what is wrong unless we can see the self assignment in context.

Comment: I added an example that should hopefully be clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you expect `self` to be defined at all inside `_moveTag`? Apparently someone is leaking a `self` into `window.self` and you are picking up the bad `self` inside `_moveTag` and that `self` happens to be `window`; given something like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.widget('ui.pancakes', {
        _create: function() {
            var self = this;
            self._moveTag();
        },
        _moveTag: function() {
            // ...
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The `self` inside `_create` is the widget you want your `self` to be but that `self` is not in scope for `_moveTag`, `_moveTag` is picking up the leaked `window.self` from somewhere else. So you can use `self` inside `_create` and any functions defined within `_create` and you get what expect; but `_moveTag` is defined as a widget method in the usual way (rather than inside `_create`'s scope) so it picks up the bad outer `self` and that `self` is `window`.

I think your private `_moveTags` method is guilty of `self` abuse. You should be using `this` inside widget methods and make sure the caller uses the correct context; jQuery-UI will call public methods with the right context for you and you should be able to handle private methods (such as `_moveTag`) quite easily on your own.

Here's a quick demo for illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/UhE3F/

---

A little investigation reveals a shocking fact: `window` is supposed to have a [`self` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self):

> **window.self**
>
> Returns an object reference to the window object.

and it turns out that the `var self = this` convention is one of the worst ideas ever or at least using the name `self` for this is an awful idea. What a lovely source of confusing bugs this is.

Comment: Nobody's leaking `window.self`, the `window` object always exposes a [self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.self) property that evaluates to itself.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Yeah, I just realized that, I've never actually used it myself and now I have to change my own awful `var self` habit to avoid irritating bugs like this. Any idea whose fault this awful `var self` convention is? I think a good old fashion witch burning is order :)

Comment: Yup, using `self` as an alias to `this` should be done with care, forget to declare it as a local and you will end up messing with the `window` object, which is not a good thing...

Comment: Ah you are correct, I have no idea why I was using `self` there instead of `this`... anyway, a green tick for you!

Comment: and yeah, any idea on why self resolves to the window object? it seems a bit of a wasted variable...

Comment: Btw, love your widget name ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: And now I have to reprogram my fingers to say `var _this` or `var that` after years of juggling live hand grenades by using `var self`. Ugh, oh well, there's always a nice bottle of red to help.